# change font color conditionally in multiple columns using gt()

Tags: r, gt

This question is related to this one: [How can I color the same value in the same color in the entire gt table in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71196794/how-can-i-color-the-same-value-in-the-same-color-in-the-entire-gt-table-in-r)

**Basically the OP asks to change the font color in an gt object conditionally:**

if value == 4 -> font blue
if value == 0 -> font red

It turned out that it is not as easy as I thought. I managed to change the colors in specific columns like:

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = cell_text(color = "red", weight = "bold"),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = am,
      rows = am == 0
    )
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = cell_text(color = "blue", weight = "bold"),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = cyl,
      rows = cyl == 4
    )
  )
```

which gives:
[image]

**My question:**
How can I modify my code to apply these condition to all columns!

**e.g all `0` are red and all `4` are blue!**

Comment: Have you tried the loop in the link

Comment: Yes. But loops are still mysterious for me. So I failed so far. But I will try again. My question is intended to modify `columns` argument which is possible with `columns = c(vs, am, etc...)`, but then I don't know how to adapt the `rows` argument!

Comment: Could you please show as answer here!

Comment: Posted an option with `across`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want only to do this on particular columns, create a vector of names ('nm1') and loop over only those columns, within the loop, get the index that meets the condition in `rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
 tbl1 <- mtcars %>% 
     gt()
 nm1 <- c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
 for(i in seq_along(nm1)) {
      
      tbl1 <- tbl1 %>%
        tab_style(
          style = list(
            cell_text(color = "red", weight = "bold")
            
          ),
          locations = cells_body(
            columns = nm1[i],
            
            rows = tbl1$`_data`[[nm1[i]]] == 0 
          )
        ) %>%
        
        tab_style(
          style = list(
            cell_text(color = "blue", weight = "bold")
            
          ),
          locations = cells_body(
            columns = nm1[i],
            
            rows = tbl1$`_data`[[nm1[i]]] == 4 
          )
        ) 
        
    }
```

-output

[image]

---

Another option would be to create the `gt` object in each column using `across`, store `as_raw_html` and then call the `gt` on top of the output with `fmt_markdown`

```
out <-  mtcars %>%
    summarise(across(everything(),  ~ 
                          setNames(tibble(.x), cur_column()) %>%
                                  gt() %>%
                                 tab_style(
                                   style = cell_text(color = "red", weight = "bold"),
                                   locations = cells_body(
                                     columns = cur_column(),
                                     rows = .x == 0
                                   )
                                 ) %>% 
                                 tab_style(
                                   style = cell_text(color = "blue", weight = "bold"),
                                   locations = cells_body(
                                     columns = cur_column(),
                                     rows = .x == 4
                                   )
                                 ) %>%
                       as_raw_html()
                                          
    ))
 
out1 <- out %>%
     gt() %>%
   fmt_markdown(columns = everything())
out1
```

Comment: This is perfect master. I tried across with case_when but realized soon the limits of my knowledge! Thank you!!!

Comment: @TarJae no problem.  There is a dupe column name row, which I think it is from the previous step, I guess there is a way to remove that row